# How can i fix this error " Error: Failed to prepare query: ERROR: syntax error at or near "ORDER"

Tags: r, postgresql

I am trying to compute the compute the nearest health facility for each school and distance in kilometers and add these fields to the school relation using R

Here is my code

```
 query <- "
    UPDATE school
        SET nearest_health_facility = h.id,
        distance_to_health_facility = ST_Distance( ST_Transform(schools.geom,21097),
        ST_Transform(health_facility.geom,21097))/1000
    FROM health_facility h
    WHERE s.id = school.id
    ORDER BY ST_Distance(s.geom, h.geom)
    LIMIT 1
    "
    dbExecute(con, query)
```

Comment: Your table alias `s` appears to be undefined.  You appear to want to join two tables but reference only one in your `FROM` clause.

Comment: @Limey This `update` form does implicit (old style)  Join on the table in the `from` clause to the table being updated. [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) Update parameters:*from_item* "A table expression allowing columns from other tables to appear in the WHERE condition and update expressions. This uses the same syntax as the FROM clause of a SELECT statement; for example, an alias for the table name can be specified. ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UPDATE` command doesn't have `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` clauses. The following query should produce the desired results:

```
UPDATE school
  SET nearest_health_facility = nearest.health_facility_id,
      distance_to_health_facility = nearest.distance / 1000
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (s.id) s.id AS school_id,
               h.id AS health_facility_id,
               ST_Distance(ST_Transform(s.geom, 21097), ST_Transform(h.geom, 21097)) AS distance
          FROM school s
          CROSS JOIN health_facility h
          ORDER BY s.id, distance, h.id) nearest
  WHERE nearest.school_id = school.id;
```

If there are a large number of schools and health facilities, then the subquery, `nearest`, will likely need to be replaced with a more efficient nearest neighbor query.